# WinRT WinJS + C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm new to the WinRT space.Our company has started developing a windows 8 store app.I initially started doing it in XAML / C# until I realized I can use javascript and html with WINJS ;).

I Have have written a lot of C# code to do calls specifically methods using HTTPClient for REST calls.

1.Will I be able to reuse those methods and call them from my JS?
2.Do I need to re-package them in a class lib or runtime component
3.How do I access these classes in javascript?

Any push in the right direction would be very helpful.

Many thanks.

Comment: if your app connects to a web service thru rest api, may be you can think of putting a service client wrapper in winrt and use it from view model in js code.

Comment: Do you have an example of doing this?

Comment: as of now, I have not hit the code reuse between c# and JS for my apps. I have written them fully in winjs or c#. hence, i do not have sample code.

Comment: TRANSLATE c# to javascript:  JSIL, scriptsharp, SharpKit, bridge.net, or cshtml5.  I don't know whether these work well with WinRT or WinJS, but it is what I would try to do.  AFAIK, These solutions are intended to allow you to continue developing in C#, essentially using javascript as the "assembly language" for deployment. (In contrast to a one-time translation from one language to another, as a way to aid porting to a different platform.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to repackage them. Create a Windows Runtime Component project from file-new project (and not the class library type). When you compile you'll see what you need to fix as there are some restrictions on types.

Classes need to be sealed, can't inherit (except in limited cases) and other restrictions. This project type creates the .winmd (metadata) that can be used by your JavaScript app.

The important note is from here: [.NET Framework Support for Windows Store Apps and Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694558.aspx)

> If your component will be used only with C# or Visual Basic, there's no reason to make it a Windows Runtime component. If you make it an ordinary .NET Framework class library instead, you don't have to restrict its public API surface to Windows Runtime types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The more I look into WinJS the more I have my doubts.It seem that you loose a lot in the way of databing? Would this be accurate? I have a bunch of JSON objects defined that work with my HTTP client.I don't see any straight forward way of bind them to html?

Comment: plennntttty of binding options through WinJS or any binding framework- see my blog post: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/04/windows-8-listview-data-binding.html  if you are looking at different scenarios ask me, sure I can think of something.

Comment: Thanks,my objects sit in C#.I'll fool around a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you change you C# types to be WinRT types you should be able call them from JS. Here is the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get you started

Comment: Be aware though, that its not recommended to mix C# and JS in one app. Because loading .net components brings in the .net Runtime into the wwahost.exe process an increases your apps memory footprint dramatically.

Comment: @philk where is it recommended to avoid it? The option is available for exactly these types of situations. I wouldn't recommend rewriting your code base to avoid this.

Comment: it's not recommended by MSFT, according to http://kraigbrockschmidt.com/blog/?p=497

Beside that, the scenario the OP describes does not seem overly complicated to realize in just plain JS. It's possible to use C# in JS yes, but it hurts your apps memory footprint and makes it more likely your app is one of the first being shutdown because of that.